# Does one document or one field is charged as one read in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In Cloud Firestore, I have 1 collection, in that i have 100 documents and in each document i have 10 fields. How many reads it counts for pricing in cloud firestore?

+Add collection(1)     +Add document(1...100)   + Add field(1,2...10)(1,2...10)....

I searched for this question but i didn't understand clearly. I am new to database.Please help me. I am using firestore database in flutter app. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does one document or one field is charged as one read in cloud Firestore?

Yes, it does.

> In Cloud Firestore, I have 1 collection, in which I have 100 documents and in each document, I have 10 fields. How many reads does it count for pricing in Firestore?

If you update all 100 documents in a single go, it will cost you 100 write operations, no matter how many fields you update within each document.

If you update a field in a document and after some time you update it again, you'll be charged with two write operations.

Comment: To clarify the first answer: you are charged for one document read when you read a document from the server. There is no per-field charge, although of course a document with more fields will typically consume more bandwidth.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, puf.